# How to get rid of extra spacing in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, spaces, android-linearlayout

I've built a widget that uses a LinearLayout and I've put two TextViews in the layout.
The gravity of the layout is "top".

The problem is that I get a space between the two TextViews and I can't get rid of it.

```
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Text01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" 
        android:text="blah blah"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="#3e6eb4"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        />        

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" 
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="#3e6eb4"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:padding="0sp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0sp"
        />
```

As you can see I tried putting padding 0 and verticalSpacing 0 but I still get a space between them.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean space between text in two TextViews?

Comment: sp is usually used for font size, for other things use dp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: @Orsol: yes, the vertical space between the two TextViews

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try using a negative margin (just like [CSS](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=b0029) :)

(I did it with my App and it works great)

```
<TextView
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following properties :

```
<TextView
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using sp instead of dp for some of you attributes.  Only use sp for font sizes. :)